# Code base maintenance across multiple PCs and setups

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, cvs

We have a lab where we have 4 setups - each setup has two linux PCs and one windows PC.

One setup is required to test our entire system since our system consists of 3 components - each PC in the setup runs one of the components.

For example, Setup 1 has,

Linux PC A running Component 1,
Linux PC B running Component 2,
Windows PC C running Component 3,

We use CVS for version control.Every day engineers are working on the 4 setups - the great challenge is how to sync Component 1, 2 and 3 across the 4 setups everyday so that all setups are running the same code.

Suggestions and ideas are most welcome on how to effectively merge and do source code management so that the same code runs for each component in all 4 setups

Thanks

Comment: For linux machines you could use https://www.docker.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention continuous integration I am going to suggest that you setup one Jenkins server. Then install slaves on all the PC's that you need to keep in sync. For each of these PC you then create a job in Jenkins that will perform the synchronization you need.